# Angular Unit Testing for ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am doing unit testing for angular components using Jasmine Karma and facing below error

```
TypeError: this.subscription.unsubscribe is not a function at ScheduledNewContributionsViewComponent.ngOnDestroy (webpack:///./src/app/contributions/scheduled-new-contributions-view/scheduled-new-contributions-view.component.ts?:154:31) at callProviderLifecycles
```

This error shows in console when I run unit test for ScheduledNewContributionsViewComponent.
Although my tests are being passed but console window is full of this one error.Its keep on coming on each test.

Below is my ts file

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.subscription = this.contributionService.editContribution$.subscribe(
              data => {
                this.scheduledContributionData = data;
                this.headerTitle = this.contributionService.getLabel('ACCTTAB.COMMONREQUESTS.MANAGECONTRIBUTIONS.EDIT');
}
        this.loadEditScheduledContributionData(this.scheduledContributionData);
      });

ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    if (this.subscription) 
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    // if(this.deleteSubscription)
    // this.deleteSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

For contributeService Icreated stub and mocked editContribution$

```
 class ContributionServiceStub {

      editContribution$ = {
        subscribe: function(data) {
          return Observable.of(data);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Well, your fake subscribe() function, instead of returning a Subscription, returns an Observable. editContribution$ should **be** an observable: `editContribution$ = Observable.of(data)`.

Comment: When I do that it says editContribution$ is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stub function is incorrect. It is returning an observable when the `subscribe` is called, but it should be returning a subscription instead.

```
class ContributionServiceStub {
  editContribution$ = Observable.of(data);
}
```

I would just assign the observable to the `editContribution$` property.